# How to verify subscription of user from developer account of iTunes?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, in-app-purchase, itunes

I am facing one issue. I have integrated iOS in-app purchase plugin in my Cordova phone-gap app. In-app purchase plugin is working fine but sometimes due to some issues subscription will be paid but I am not able to get return response on server side because it will not hit my server side file where I have add API to fetch response but its subscription will be paid and user will receive receipt with order ID, Document Number.

Now the question is how do I verify from my iTunes developer account that user is subscribed or not. In my sales report I will get only subscriber ID field and not getting any order ID, receipt Number etc.

So is there any alternate way to verify user's subscription status?

Thanks